# insert paragraph tag in exp_channel_data field?

Tags: ee2, html, table, html-entities, encryption

I am inserting a para in one of the fields in table `exp_channel_data`.

The problem i am facing while retrieving that data.

Suppose if the inserted para is like :

`Kawhi Leonard had 22 points and seven rebounds as the San Antonio Spurs advanced to the Western Conference final with a dominant 104-82 win over Portland to give them a 4-1 series victory.<br/>Danny Green scored 22 points and Tim Duncan added 16 points with eight rebounds as the Spurs ensured a third straight conference final.<br/>Duncan said the Spurs are starting to come together at the right time.<br/>"We got to the point now where we understand how we need to play for a longer period of time," Duncan said.<br/>`

Please notice the br tag.

When I retrieve it back on my page,I get the br tags inside the decription..Is there any way i can make the br or p tag work?

Comment: What kind of field are you using, and what do you have the field formatting set as?

Comment: datatype used is text .Dint understood the field formatting part..?

Comment: @DerekHogue http://tensports.zeecdn.com/news/other/140-billion-lost-in-sport-betting-24236

Comment: Looks at the [fieldtype settings screen](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/custom_fields_edit.html) for the field in question. What are the values for **Fieldtype** and **Default Text Formatting**?

Comment: @DerekHogue : text area and none respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the [Channel Fields Settings](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/custom_fields_edit.html) screen for the field in question, and change the **Default text Formatting** to "XHTML".

Once you've done that, you can also remove the `<br/>` tags, and simply enter a single carriage return to create them. (Two carriage returns will create a paragraph.)

Comment: ok..trying..basically i will have 3 to 4 sentences and EE will automatically create paragraph?

Comment: Yes: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/text_formatting.html

Comment: naa..dint work..  http://tensports.zeecdn.com/news/tennis/Barty-Kyrios-among-French-Open-wild-cards-24261

The description is entirely missing paragraph

Comment: worked!!!thanks a ton..I have followed a lot of ur answers on EE.Thanks man.

Comment: I have set a cron for pulling up feeds.setting up xhtml as default text formatting works fine..but when the next feeds come in to the table..It again behaves the previous way,showing up tags on the page.When i cross cheked the default text formatting field..it was xhtml.Why this happens?I hope i am clear.

Comment: When you changed it, did you check the box that said "update all existing entries with this setting"? If not, change it back to none, save it, then change it back to XHTML again and make sure you check that box.

Comment: Exactly my point..i already tried that..but for things to work perfectly i need to do the same thing over and over again..which obviously isnt the right thing to do

Comment: P tags dont work.Everything gets enclosed inside a string.However if try \n..it works.But then again the same old problem..a new entry would look like this http://tensports.zeecdn.com/news/football/Ronaldo-to-return-against-Espanyol-24365